# Cannot resolve method 'create(okhttp3.MediaType, java.util.List<java.lang.String>)'

Tags: java, android, api, okhttp

I have to send a request with a list of Strings but I don't know how

I used this for string before:

```
RequestBody title = RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("text/plain"),   
                    post.getTitle());
```

So the question is: how to send a request with a list of strings?

Comment: Want to send your data in list to server??

Comment: @Piyush
yes , api request has many data and one of them is list of string

Comment: So you can use _HashMap<String,String>_ and put your all data in it and send it to server

Answer (score 2):

there is [no default `create` method](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/RequestBody.html) which takes a list of `Strings` as a param

but still you have `byte[]` or even single `String`. convert your list to some JSON array and deserialize data on server side (remember about different `MediaType` for JSON)

most trivial way even without JSON or any other structure: declare some separator, e.g. `_SEP_` and join all your `String`s into one with this separator between each. then on server side just split received `String` by recognizing declared separator. ugly, but will work for some basic system and experimenting (still some structure, e.g. JSON, is strongly suggested in your case)